# Dedicated Server HTTPD Error

Tags: linux, apache, centos, centos6

Recently I edited some files on my dedicated server (CentOS 6 64 bit) and when I decided to restart httpd I received the following error:

> Starting httpd: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain for ServerName

Does anybody know how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Look in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf for ServerName. Change that:

ServerName www.yourwebserver.com:80

Restart httpd.

Comment: Nope, no fix. Do i need to change anything in my hosts.conf? Here it is localhost   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

Comment: Here is the servername for my httpd.conf: #ServerName www.example.com:80
ServerName localhost:80

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure the hostname you are using is reverse mapped.  Or that it's defined in DNS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the /etc/hosts file.

It should be like :

127.0.0.1 yourservername.yourdomain yourservername

Please be sure that this line appears once.